# Usando o Firebase para armazenar imagens e trazer na tela do Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Bom dia, eu criei um RecyclerView com CardView para mostrar umas fotos que estão armazenadas no Firebase, mas ao trazer a fotos para a tela a mesma não se encaixa no cardView que eu deixei a imagem como android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent", eu queira que a imagem pegasse todo o espaço que eu reservei para ela no cardView, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Layout do CardView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleId"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitleId"
        android:text="@string/subtitle"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Imagem de retorno no aplicativo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha MainActivity, mostro só a chamada do Firebase.

```
private void prepareCard() {

    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            Item data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
            cardList.add(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

Inseri na classe Adapter no metodo onBindViewHolder a seguinte linha no meu caso eu uso o Glide **.centerCrop()**

Ex:`public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item item = cardList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.getImage())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}`
```